# Best approach to test home screen widget

Tags: android, android-widget, android-testing, android-espresso

What is the best approach to test android home screen widget ?
Its very difficult to find any example code :/
What frameworks support that tests ?

1. Espresso
2. Robotium
3. other

Answer (score 3):

try UIAutomator
use android-sdk/tools/uiautomatorviewer to get widget properties

```
    import android.test.InstrumentationTestCase;
    import android.support.test.uiautomator.UiDevice;
    import android.support.test.uiautomator.By;

    public class CalculatorUiTest extends InstrumentationTestCase {

        private UiDevice mDevice;

        public void setUp() {
            // Initialize UiDevice instance
            mDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(getInstrumentation());

            // Start from the home screen
            mDevice.pressHome();

            UiObject widgetButton = mDevice.findObject(new UiSelector()
            .text("OK"))
            .className("android.widget.Button"));

            widgetButton.clickAndWaitForNewWindow();
        }
}
```

[Android Testing Support Library](https://developer.android.com/tools/testing-support-library/index.html#UIAutomator)

Answer (score 1):

### Update May 2020

This is how I do in my project

Add Test dependencies

```
//Testing
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.3.0-beta01';
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0-beta01';

// UiAutomator Testing
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.uiautomator:uiautomator:2.2.0';
androidTestImplementation 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.3'
```

**In the Android Project View**

Go to **src->androidTest-> java->packagename** add a new test class

Now simply use **UIAutomator** to navigate to the Home Screen of the Launcher by pressing the Home Button.

On the home screen, if your widget is added you can use *`findObject`* method to get views of the widget. And once you have the view object for your `RemoteView`, you can do whatever you like.

Here is a simple widget test case example for checking if the widget is added and launches your app:

```
import androidx.test.filters.SdkSuppress;
import androidx.test.platform.app.InstrumentationRegistry;
import androidx.test.uiautomator.By;
import androidx.test.uiautomator.UiDevice;
import androidx.test.uiautomator.UiObject2;
import androidx.test.uiautomator.Until;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.hamcrest.core.IsNull.notNullValue;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

@SdkSuppress(minSdkVersion = 18)
public class WidgetAddedTest {
    private static final String APP_PACKAGE_NAME = "com.example.myweather";
    private static final int LAUNCH_TIMEOUT = 5000;
    private UiDevice device;

    @Before
    public void startMainActivityFromHomeScreen() {
        // Initialize UiDevice instance
        device = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());

        // Start from the home screen
        device.pressHome();

        // Wait for launcher
        final String launcherPackage = device.getLauncherPackageName();
        assertThat(launcherPackage, notNullValue());
        device.wait(Until.hasObject(By.pkg(launcherPackage).depth(0)),
                LAUNCH_TIMEOUT);
    }
    @Test
    public void widgetAddedTest() {
        //Check text on Widget
        UiObject2 titleTextView = device.findObject(By.res(APP_PACKAGE_NAME, "title"));
        assertEquals("Weather", titleTextView.getText());

        //CHeck correct value on Widget
        UiObject2 temperatureTextView = device.findObject(By.res(APP_PACKAGE_NAME, "temperatureTextView"));
        assertEquals("20", temperatureTextView.getText());

        //Launch App From Widget Test
        temperatureTextView.click();

        // Wait for the app to appear
        device.wait(Until.hasObject(By.pkg(APP_PACKAGE_NAME).depth(0)),
                LAUNCH_TIMEOUT);

        //Check if the app is launched from the widget
        UiObject2 toolBar = device.findObject(By.res(APP_PACKAGE_NAME, "toolBar"));
        assertEquals("My Weather", toolBar.getText());

    }


}
```